# Should not the flag history page report that "disputed flags" include also the flags that have been marked as invalid from the user?

Tags: discussion, flag-history

As far as I understood, when I flag a flag as invalid, my flag will always be marked as disputed.
If this is the case, should not the flag history page report that fact?

[image: screenshot]

For example, a note as the following one could help:

> Disputed flags include also the flags you flagged as invalid, and on which other users have agreed.

Comment: Can I clarify - is your question here "should the screen state more clearly what disputed means"? because it *does* already *report* it as disputed...?

Comment: In another question I was said that flagging a flag as invalid marks my flag as disputed. My suggestion is to make that clear, as the text seems to suggest that disputed flags are only the flags such as "not an answer" for which somebody else disagreed. If I understood correctly, in the case of "invalid flags," somebody could agree with me that the original flag was invalid.

Comment: in that scenario it is disputed for everyone; for a disputed flag there is no "winner" or "loser"... but yes, it is possible that someone agreed with the flag and somebody disagreed with it.

Comment: I normally understand as _disputed_ a flag for which somebody else has chosen "invalid flags"; for that, I get somebody disagreed with me. When I use "invalid flags" for a post flagged from somebody else, and another user uses "invalid flags" too, my flag is marked as disputed. In that case, the other user could have meant to consider invalid the original flag, not mine.